# Printing QR code with a parameter in Zebra language

Tags: qr-code, zebra-printers

I'm trying to print a QR code including a parameter on a label

I need to take this value:

```
^A0R,33,26^FO301,296^FV#01/HarnessId;02/02;03/
HarnessId (z.B. 999):;04/-;05/param_HarnessIdCnt#^FS
```

and put it in a QR code. I tried this, but i doesn't print anything:

```
    ^BXN,10,20,,,,,2^FO153,43^FV#01/HarnessId;02/02;03/
    HarnessId (z.B. 999):;04/-;05/param_HarnessIdCnt#^FS
```

Comment: ^BX is the command for a DataMatrix code try using ^BQ

Answer (score 0):

you should try with the BQ command

[Link to viewer](http://labelary.com/viewer.html?density=8&width=4&height=6&units=inches&index=0&zpl=%5EXA%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%5EBQN%2C10%2C20%2C%2C%2C%2C%2C2%5EFO153%2C43%5EFV%2301%2FHarnessId%3B02%2F02%3B03%2F%0A%20%20%20%20HarnessId%20(z.B.%20999)%3A%3B04%2F-%3B05%2Fparam_HarnessIdCnt%23%5EFS%0A%0A%5EXZ)